# Seq2Seq/ NLP/Translation: After generating the target sentence, does the last decoder hidden state carry any residual meaning?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, artificial-intelligence, recurrent-neural-network, machine-translation

I am studying machine translation right now and I am interested in a question probing a bit more deeply into the internals of sentence representations.

Suppose we train an encoder-decoder Seq2Seq En-Fr translation system on parallel corpora, starting with pre-trained Eng and Fr word vectors. The system can use anything to form the sentence embedding (Transformers, LSTMs, etc). Then the job of the Seq2Seq translation system is to learn to build Eng sentence representations from Eng word vectors and learn to build French sentence representations from French word vectors and by the linking of the encoder and decoder, learn those two sentence representations in the same space.

After training the model, and encoding some English sentence with the model (Say, "This is not a pipe."), the sentence embedding in the joint representation space has some idea of the words 'this', 'is', 'not', 'a', 'pipe', etc and all their associations as well as the sequence in which they appear. (1)

When the decoder is run on the encoding, it is able to take out the aforementioned information due for a load of corpora that was fed to it during training and statistical associations between words, and output, correspondingly, 'Ceci', 'n', ''', 'est', 'pas', 'une', 'pipe', '(EOS)'. At each step, it extracts and outputs the next French word from the decoder hidden state and transforms it so that the heuristically "most prominent" word to be decoded next can be found by the decoder, and so on, until '(EOS)'.

My question is this: Is there any interpretation of the last decoder hidden state after (EOS) is the output? Is it useful for anything else? Of course, an easy answer is "no, the model was trained to capture millions of lines of English text and process them until some word in conjunction with the hidden state produces (EOS) and last decoder hidden state is simply that, everything else not explicitly trained on is just noise and not signal".

But I'm wondering if there's anything more to this? What I'm trying to get at is, if you have a sentence embedding generated in English, and have the meaning dumped out of it in French by the decoder model, does any residual meaning remain that is not translatable from English to French? Certainly, the last hidden state for any particular sentence's translation would be very hard to interpret, but how about in the aggregate (like some aggregation of the last hidden states of every single sentence to be translated that has the words 'French' in it, which means something slightly different in English because it can be paired with 'fries' etc. This is a silly example, but you can probably think of others exploiting cultural ambiguities, etc, that turn up in language.) Might this last embedding capture some statistical "uncertainty" or ambiguity about the translation (maybe of like the English possible "meanings" and associations that could have ended up in French but didn't?) or some other structural aspect of the language that might be used to help us understand, say, how English is different from French?

What category do you think the answer to this fall in?

- "There is no signal",
- "There probably is some signal but it would be
  very hard to extract because of depends on the mechanics of how the
  model was trained"
- "There is a signal that can be reliably extracted,
  even if we have to aggregate over millions of examples"?

I'm not sure if this question is sensical at all but I'm curious about the answer and if any research been done on this front? I ask out of plain simple curiosity.

**Notes**: 
I am aware that the last hidden state exists because it generates (EOS) in conjunction with the last word. That is its purpose, nothing else (?) makes it special. I'm wondering if we can get any more meaning out of it (even if it means transforming it like applying the decoder step one more time to it or something).

(1) (Of course, the ML model has no rich ides of 'concepts' as a human would with all its associations to thoughts and experiences and feelings, to the ML model the 'concept' only has associations with other words seen in the monolingual corpus for the word vector training and the bilingual corpus for translation training.)

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question but still interested in thoughts. I have a hunch the answer is "no", because the hidden state embedding is generated with only two properties in mind: (1) To be 'closest' by cosine distance to the next output token out of all tokens in French, and (2) to produce the hidden state corresponding to the next word when the decoder transformation is applied to it. To make the last hidden state have an interpretation other than 'it is the point on the 300-d (or whatever dimension embedding we are using) unit circle closes by cosine distance to the French (EOS) token' would mean we would have apply (2) to it. But the training data never had any examples of anything following (EOS) so what we get if we apply the decoder transformation to the last hidden state was never learned and is simply random depending on our model initialisations.

If we wanted to get some sort of idea about how good a 'match' the English and French joint embedding space is, we should be looking and comparing the test loss of various translations, not looking into the last hidden state. But still interested in people's thoughts on the matter if anyone thinks differently.